# Проблема с ботом на Heroku

Tags: python, telebot, heroku

Написал бота и загрузил на HEROKU, но после запуска, через 60 секунд вылетают такие логи:

```
2022-07-19T16:55:23.130953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-19T16:55:23.227546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-19T16:55:23.407912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-19T16:55:23.695291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728830/heroku-process-exited-with-status-137-node-js-app может быть..

Comment: Не совсем просто понимаю как это работает, я нашел решение через смену порта тоже, но не понял и на нашел как его сменить.